# Eigen: random binary vector with t 1s

Tags: c++, random, eigen

I want to compute `K*es` where `K` is an `Eigen` matrix (dimension `pxp`) and `es` is a `px1` random binary vector with 1s.

For example if `p=5` and `t=2` a possible `es` is `[1,0,1,0,0]'` or `[0,0,1,1,0]'` and so on...

How do I easily generate `es` with `Eigen`?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with even a better solution, which is a combination of `std::vector`, `Egien::Map` and `std::shuffle`.

```
std::vector<int> esv(p,0);
std::fill_n(esv.begin(),t,1);
Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi> es (esv.data(), esv.size());
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());
std::shuffle(std::begin(esv), std::end(esv), g);
```

This solution is memory efficient (since `Eigen::Map` doesn't copy `esv`) and has the big advantage that if we want to permute `es` several times (like in this case), then we just need to repeat `std::shuffle(std::begin(esv), std::end(esv), g);`

Maybe I'm wrong, but this solution seems more elegant and efficient than the previous ones.

Comment: Looks good. Shuffle is O(n), better than sort. But you solution need to generate p random numbers rather than t. Could you replace the fixed numbers like 10 and 3 with variable names like p and t so it is more readable?  You don't need std::vector as VectorXi can do the same thing.

Comment: Sorry I replaced the numbers with `p` and `t`. Anyway I'm pretty sure that I can't use `std::shuflle` with `Eigen::VectorXi` (I need standard iterators) or use `std::fill_n`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Pointer is a iterator. See how I call std::sort

Answer (score 0):

So you're using Eigen. I'm not sure what matrix type you're using, but I'll go off the class `Eigen::MatrixXd`.

What you need to do is:

- Create a 1xp matrix that's all 0
- Choose random spots to flip from 0 to 1 that are between 0-p, and make sure that spot is unique.

The following code should do the trick, although you could implement it other ways.

```
//Your p and t
int p = 5;
int t = 2;

//px1 matrix
MatrixXd es(1, p);

//Initialize the whole 1xp matrix
for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i)
        es(1, i) = 0;

//Get a random position in the 1xp matrix from 0-p
for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i)
{
    int randPos = rand() % p;

    //If the position was already a 1 and not a 0, get a different random position
    while (es(1, randPos) == 1)
        randPos = rand() % p;

    //Change the random position from a 0 to a 1
    es(1, randPos) = 1;
}
```

Comment: please give a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

When `t` is close to `p`, Ryan's method need to generate much more than `t` random numbers. To avoid this performance degrade, you could solve your original problem

> find `t` different numbers from [0, p) that are uniformly distributed

by the following steps

1. generate `t` uniformly distributed random numbers `idx[t]` from [0, p-t+1)
2. sort these numbers `idx[t]`
3. `idx[i]+i, i=0,...,t-1` are the result

The code:

```
VectorXi idx(t);
VectorXd es(p);
es.setConstant(0);

for(int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
  idx(i) = int(double(rand()) / RAND_MAX * (p-t+1));
}

std::sort(idx.data(), idx.data() + idx.size());

for(int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
  es(idx(i)+i) = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: please give a look at my answer