# Eigen: multiply a float matrix by a bool vector

Tags: c++, vector, bit, eigen

I need to perform `A*v` in `Eigen` where `v` is a vector of size `p` with `t` ones in random positions and `p-t` zeros, for more details look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335328/generate-bit-vector-with-t-random-ones) question.

My first question is: there is any way to do it in `Eigen`? If you know how to do it, please answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333326/eigen-random-binary-vector-with-t-1s/38334321#38334321) question.

My second question is: in the first linked question I found a time and memory efficient method via `std::vector<bool>`, then it would be pretty easy to use it through `Eigen::Map`.

The problem is that I tried to do the following (just for testing purpose):

```
Eigen::Matrix<bool,2,1> v;
Eigen::Matrix<float,2,2> A;
v<<1,0;
A<<1,2,3,4;
A*v;
```

But I get a compile error (find it at the end of the question). How can I do it? A simple workaround could be declaring `Eigen::Matrix<float,2,1> v;` but this could be really memory inefficient (especially considering that `v` could be big).

```
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h: In instantiation of ‘struct Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >’:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:41:34:   required from ‘class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >’
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:48:34:   required from ‘class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >’
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h:114:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6>’
../Math.hpp:83:7:   required from ‘static void Math::createHashTable(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, int) [with T = float]’
../CloudCache.cpp:155:58:   required from here
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h:43:112: error: no type named ‘ReturnType’ in ‘struct Eigen::internal::scalar_product_traits<float, bool>’
   typedef typename scalar_product_traits<typename _LhsNested::Scalar, typename _RhsNested::Scalar>::ReturnType Scalar;
                                                                                                                ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h:69:51: error: no type named ‘ReturnType’ in ‘struct Eigen::internal::scalar_product_traits<float, bool>’
                           || ( (ColsAtCompileTime % packet_traits<Scalar>::size) == 0
                                                   ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h:76:51: error: no type named ‘ReturnType’ in ‘struct Eigen::internal::scalar_product_traits<float, bool>’
                           || ( (RowsAtCompileTime % packet_traits<Scalar>::size) == 0
                                                   ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h:94:63: error: no type named ‘ReturnType’ in ‘struct Eigen::internal::scalar_product_traits<float, bool>’
                     : InnerSize * (NumTraits<Scalar>::MulCost + LhsCoeffReadCost + RhsCoeffReadCost)
                                                               ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h:95:41: error: no type named ‘ReturnType’ in ‘struct Eigen::internal::scalar_product_traits<float, bool>’
                       + (InnerSize - 1) * NumTraits<Scalar>::AddCost,
                                         ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h:107:41: error: no type named ‘ReturnType’ in ‘struct Eigen::internal::scalar_product_traits<float, bool>’
                           && (InnerSize % packet_traits<Scalar>::size == 0)
                                         ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:278:0,
                 from ../Math.hpp:13,
                 from ../CloudCache.cpp:15:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h: In instantiation of ‘class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >’:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:48:34:   required from ‘class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >’
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h:114:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6>’
../Math.hpp:83:7:   required from ‘static void Math::createHashTable(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, int) [with T = float]’
../CloudCache.cpp:155:58:   required from here
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:67:25: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::operator*;
                         ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:68:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::derived;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:69:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::const_cast_derived;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:70:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::rows;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:71:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::cols;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:72:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::size;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:73:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::rowIndexByOuterInner;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:74:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::colIndexByOuterInner;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:75:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::coeff;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:76:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::coeffByOuterInner;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:77:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::packet;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:78:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::packetByOuterInner;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:79:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::writePacket;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:80:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::writePacketByOuterInner;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:81:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::coeffRef;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:82:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::coeffRefByOuterInner;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:83:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::copyCoeff;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:84:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::copyCoeffByOuterInner;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:85:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::copyPacket;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:86:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::copyPacketByOuterInner;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:87:26: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::operator();
                          ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:88:26: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::operator[];
                          ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:89:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::x;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:90:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::y;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:91:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::z;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:92:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::w;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:93:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::stride;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:94:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::innerStride;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:95:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::outerStride;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:96:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::rowStride;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:97:17: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
     using Base::colStride;
                 ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:279:0,
                 from ../Math.hpp:13,
                 from ../CloudCache.cpp:15:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h: In instantiation of ‘class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >’:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h:114:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6>’
../Math.hpp:83:7:   required from ‘static void Math::createHashTable(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, int) [with T = float]’
../CloudCache.cpp:155:58:   required from here
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:71:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}::derived’ in ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}’
     using Base::derived;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:72:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}::const_cast_derived’ in ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}’
     using Base::const_cast_derived;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:73:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}::rows’ in ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}’
     using Base::rows;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:74:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}::cols’ in ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}’
     using Base::cols;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:75:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}::size’ in ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}’
     using Base::size;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:76:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}::coeff’ in ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}’
     using Base::coeff;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:77:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}::coeffRef’ in ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}’
     using Base::coeffRef;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:79:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}::eval’ in ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}’
     using Base::eval;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:82:25: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}::operator*=’ in ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}’
     using Base::operator*=;
                         ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:83:25: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}::operator/=’ in ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}’
     using Base::operator/=;
                         ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:20:0,
                 from ../Math.hpp:13,
                 from ../CloudCache.cpp:15:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h: In instantiation of ‘class Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6>’:
../Math.hpp:83:7:   required from ‘static void Math::createHashTable(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, int) [with T = float]’
../CloudCache.cpp:155:58:   required from here
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h:121:5: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6>::Base {aka Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}::derived’ in ‘Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6>::Base {aka class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}’
     EIGEN_DENSE_PUBLIC_INTERFACE(CoeffBasedProduct)
     ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h:121:5: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6>::Base {aka Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}::const_cast_derived’ in ‘Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6>::Base {aka class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6> >}’
     EIGEN_DENSE_PUBLIC_INTERFACE(CoeffBasedProduct)
     ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:254:0,
                 from ../Math.hpp:13,
                 from ../CloudCache.cpp:15:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h: In instantiation of ‘Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<Lhs, Rhs, NestingFlags>::CoeffBasedProduct(const Lhs&, const Rhs&) [with Lhs = Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>; Rhs = Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>; LhsNested = const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&; RhsNested = const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&; int NestingFlags = 6]’:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/GeneralProduct.h:598:91:   required from ‘const typename Eigen::ProductReturnType<Derived, OtherDerived>::Type Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::operator*(const Eigen::MatrixBase<OtherDerived>&) const [with OtherDerived = Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>; typename Eigen::ProductReturnType<Derived, OtherDerived>::Type = Eigen::CoeffBasedProduct<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2>&, const Eigen::Matrix<bool, 2, 1>&, 6>]’
../Math.hpp:83:7:   required from ‘static void Math::createHashTable(const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, int) [with T = float]’
../CloudCache.cpp:155:58:   required from here
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h:154:7: error: static assertion failed: YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY
       EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT((internal::scalar_product_traits<typename Lhs::RealScalar, typename Rhs::RealScalar>::Defined),
       ^
subdir.mk:30: recipe for target 'CloudCache.o' failed
make: *** [CloudCache.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast to the relevant type. Eigen doesn't support implicit type casting so you'd have to write:

```
A*v.cast<float>();
```

There was a hint to this in the error output:

```
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/products/CoeffBasedProduct.h:154:7: error: static assertion failed: YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY
```

Comment: Ouch, am I wrong but this `cast` operation is going to create a temporary object with same elements but with type `float`? This sounds *terribly* inefficient!

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. It's just an explicit cast. See [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a660200abaf1fc4b888330a37d6132b76). From [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/AsciiQuickReference.txt): (generally, conversion happens on-the-fly)

Comment: if the number of false is large, better use a manual for loop doing `if(v(i) res+=A.col(i)`.